# Which maven dependency can be used for getting updated Jackson dependency fetched as transitive dependency?

Tags: java, json, spring, maven, jackson

Spring 5.x versions requires jackson dependencies and they needs to me added in pom.xml explicitly.And overtime if there is version upgrade then the dependency needs to be updated.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there any jar or dependency that can be used in pom.xml (preferably spring jar) which automatically fetches the latest jackson dependency as its transitive dependency . The requirement is to avoid jackson-core jar entry in pom.xml.

spring boot dependency cannot be used as it is very heavy.

Any other solution that can execute the spring 5.x version without mentioning jackon jar dependency in pom would also help.

Comment: What's the benefit of not wanting to define a dependency you obviously need within your pom but rely on some doubtful transitive dependency? If you ever will update this dependency in a couple of month/years chances are high that eventually a couple of methods you rely on have changed and thus break your application and the developer working on the issue has to check which dependency pulled the old version in. I highly suggest to not do something along that line. If you can't, for whatever reason, then create your own dependency that only pulls in jackson, but where is the benefit actually?

Comment: which maven version are you using ?

Comment: I recommend reading this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-PluginMetaversionResolution

Comment: using version 3.3.9.So i  think LATEST is not allowed in 3.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's a good idea to manage dependencies in such way, but `spring-cloud-config` loads jackson-core for example

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would help, but there is `jackson-bom`:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson/jackson-bom

which can be imported (instead of used as parent pom) and gives consistent versions for all standard jackson components, via Maven's `dependencyManagement` section. That way you only need to add one dependency with explicit version.